# Can't Knit R Markdown File When I Use ggplot with it

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm currently doing an R Markdown File of an analysis I recently finished using R. With that, whenever I add details, I click `Knit` to ensure everything I added goes well on the HTML knit file.

I noticed that when I used `ggplot` on my R Markdown file, the file doesn't knit anymore and it says:

> Error while opening file - No Such File or directory.

[image: Error while opening file - No Such File or directory.]

But when I deleted the `ggplot` command, it gets knitted again.

[image: delete]

But this time, without the visualization, it gets knitted again.

[image: it gets knitted again.]

UPDATE: I see this error message on the console tab everytime I use ggplot on my .rmd file. [image]

So with that, I call on `install.packages("ggplot2")` & `library("ggplot2")` on my .rmd file. However, I get this error instead.
[image]

How will I be able to retain the `ggplot` command and at the same time be able to knit the file? As an added reference, the `ggplot` command executes on the .rmd file, it just doesn't knit. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What happens when you use rmarkdown::render()?

Comment: Try to put the dataframe called `employe_updated` in the same chuck.

Comment: Could you please share some code so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @TarJae, may you expound on this please? How do you do that? I'm able to call on ```employee_updated``` on my .rmd file. Just that it doesn't knit when I use ggplot on .rmd.

Comment: @Quinten `ggplot(data=employee_updated) + geom_bar(aes(x =department)) +
  coord_flip()` This is the ggplot code where I get stuck on my markdown. This is the code on the first screenshot. It executes but I can't knit the file anymore when I include this.

Comment: @diomedesdata I haven't encountered this yet. May you help me in how to try/add this please?

Comment: Don't install a package in the RMD; just call the library.

Comment: @Kat Was able to fix this already. Thank you nonetheless!